# OpenText Content Server how to get folder ID with path using REST API?

Tags: opentext

I'm trying to get the folder ID that I want to create a file at.

I have this folder's path (eg: root/folder1/folder2/folder3), so in this case, I wanted to get folder's 3 ID in order to make a POST call to create the new file.

My solution right now is just to go folder by folder, getting the child ID, but since it can be many folders I was trying to get a faster way.

Answer (score 0):

if your "folder3" folder has a nickname, you may try to use `api/v2/nicknames/{your_nickname}/nodes` endpoint

setting nickname is also possible using rest api